# Problem In Passing variables into a function based on array length

Tags: javascript, arrays, parameter-passing, p5.js

In The below Code inside the load_videos function there is a function called createVideo I want to pass the link of all the video from and array called videos is it possible to pass it based the the length of the array.
Code:

```js
function add_vid() {
  url_input = document.getElementById("vid_url");
  url = url_input.value;
  videos.push(url);
  url_input.value = "";
  load_videos();
}

function load_videos() {
    p_video = createVideo()
    start=true;
}
```

Example of what i want:
If the array videos stores `['vid1, 'vid2']` i want the createVideo function to be `createVideo(videos[0], videos[1])`
whereas id the length of the array increase the amount of videos passed in the createVideo function should increase.

Comment: Why not just pass in `videos` into the function?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `...` operator to send element one as parameter one and element two as parameter two as in the demo below:

```js
const 
   videos = ['vid1', 'vid2'],
   createVideo = (v1,v2) => console.log( v1,v2 );
   
createVideo( ...videos );
```

Comment: OP wants arbitrary length params, `createVideo = function() {console.log(Object.values(arguments));}` might be better suited

Comment: Good point @LawrenceCherone. The spread operator should work fine for whatever number of videos need to be passed. I take it the function `createVideo` has been written to **accept** a variable number of parameters.This should do it.